# Recover a predefined variable as input

Tags: python, object, input, compare, characteristics

I'm new to programming and especially to python and I have a compulsory project to do.

I explain: I have a list of objects (they are people), each one with characteristics, each characteristic is based on a scale from 1 to 5 (not important for understanding the problem) so I have 6 men and 6 women predefined as objects, I compare them according to their characteristics, if their characteristics are close they will be more or less a perfect match.

So my goal is to enter the names of the people I enter through an input and then my comparison function compares them. The problem is that when I manually compare by entering the names directly it works but when I insert an input, an error occurs.

I'll let you discover the code below to better understand what I'm saying because I don't know if I'm very understandable but I'd be very happy to have an answer to this problem, thank you :D

PS: Sorry for my spelling mistakes, I don't speak the language very well.

```py
class Candidat: #Subject class (characteristics)
    def __init__(self,genre,humour,physique,intelligence,projet):
        self.genre=genre
        self.humour=humour
        self.physique=physique
        self.intelligence=intelligence
        self.projet=projet


def compare(Test1,Test2): #comparison function

#Match à 100% :

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 100%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
       print("Mauvais Match")

#Match à 75% :

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match1")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match2")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match3")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match4")

#Match à 50% :

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match01")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match02")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match03")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match04")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match602")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match103")


#Match à 25% :

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match001")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match002")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match003")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match004")
```

Example

```
    Bryan=Candidat("homme",4,5,3,2)
    Adrien=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,3)
    Marin=Candidat("homme",5,2,4,3)
    Alcaraz=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
    Allan=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
    SebyDaddy=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
    #--------------------------------#
    Anissa=Candidat("femme",0,5,2,0)
    Melanie=Candidat("femme",5,3,4,3)
    Dita=Candidat("femme",4,4,3,2)
    LeaMary=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)
    Maissane=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)
    Kellyn=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)

    Candidat=input("Homme : ")#input Man
    Candidat=input("Femme : ")#input Woman
    compare(Test1,Test2)#comparing
```

If I write 'compare(Bryan,Dita)' for exemple, It's directly the subjects, it's working but with input it's not :/

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: What is your actual question? I can't see any.

Comment: "when I insert an input, an error occurs"...Please provide the full error traceback of the error, and the code to reproduce the error

Comment: Candidat=input("Femme : "). # Your woman overwrites your man

Comment: My question is the following if you didn't understand: I would like to be able to compare 2 objects by choosing them or rather by writing them thanks to an input, it is this part of the program that I can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your people in dicts:

```py
hommes = {}
femmes = {}

Bryan=Candidat("homme",4,5,3,2)
Adrien=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,3)
Marin=Candidat("homme",5,2,4,3)
Alcaraz=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
Allan=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
SebyDaddy=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)

hommes[‘Bryan’] = Bryan
hommes[‘Adrien’] = Adrien
hommes[‘Marin’] = Marin
hommes[‘Alcaraz’] = Alcaraz
hommes[‘Allan’] = Allan
hommes[‘SebyDaddy’] = SebyDaddy

#--------------------------------#

Anissa=Candidat("femme",0,5,2,0)
Melanie=Candidat("femme",5,3,4,3)
Dita=Candidat("femme",4,4,3,2)
LeaMary=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)
Maissane=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)
Kellyn=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)

femmes[‘Anissa’] = Anissa
femmes[‘Melanie’] = Melanie
femmes[‘Dita’] = Dita
femmes[‘LeaMary’] = LeaMary
femmes[‘Maissane’] = Maissane
femmes[‘Kellyn’] = Kellyn

homme = input("Homme : ")  #input Man
femme = input("Femme : ")  #input Woman
compare(hommes[homme],femmes[femme]) #comparing


**Update:** I had skipped putting the rest of the people into their dicts. Fixed now.
```

Comment: OMGGGG It's working !!! you are a genius, thank you very much bro !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Bryan=Candidat("homme",4,5,3,2)
Adrien=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,3)
Marin=Candidat("homme",5,2,4,3)
Alcaraz=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
Allan=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
SebyDaddy=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)
#--------------------------------#
Anissa=Candidat("femme",0,5,2,0)
Melanie=Candidat("femme",5,3,4,3)
Dita=Candidat("femme",4,4,3,2)
LeaMary=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)
Maissane=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)
Kellyn=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)

Candidat=input("Homme : ")#input Man
Candidat=input("Femme : ")#input Woman
compare(Test1,Test2)#comparing
```

You're trying to use the `input()` to determine which variable name to use.

There's no good way to do that. Variable names are for the programmer's knowledge only. However, if what you want is key-value pairs - each name pointing to a candidate - then you can use a `dict` to store everything, instead of many individual variables:

```
hommes = {
    'Bryan': Candidat("homme",4,5,3,2),
    'Adrien': Candidat("homme",4,3,2,3),
    'Marin': Candidat("homme",5,2,4,3),
    'Alcaraz': Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1),
    'Allan': Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1),
    'SebyDaddy': Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1),
}

femmes = {
    'Anissa': Candidat("femme",0,5,2,0),
    'Melanie': Candidat("femme",5,3,4,3),
    'Dita': Candidat("femme",4,4,3,2),
    'LeaMary': Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1),
    'Maissane': Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1),
    'Kellyn': Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1),
}
```

Here, we correspond *strings* to candidates in a `dict`, instead of using a bunch of *variable names*. Where before you would use the variable `Bryan`, now you would do `hommes['Bryan']` to get the same object that you declared earlier.

And unlike variable names, we can use user input to determine which of these to draw from, since `input()` returns a string:

```
candidat_homme = hommes[input("Homme : ")]
candidat_femme = femmes[input("Femme : ")]
compare(candidat_homme, candidat_femme)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you ! Your help is very useful but in your code there is an invalid syntax on the following line: 'Adrien': Candidate ("man",4,3,2,3) if I remove it the error is on the following line :/

Comment: @Ziomix My apologies, I accidentally forgot to put commas at the end of the lines.

Comment: btw, this answer should become the accepted answer because it has a more direct way of creating `hommes` and `femmes`.

Answer (score -1):

u need to use `eval` funtion

```
replace these lines
Candidat=input("Homme : ")#input Man
Candidat=input("Femme : ")#input Woman

to below lines 
man=eval(input("Homme : "))#input Man
woman=eval(input("Femme : "))#input Woman
compare(man,woman)
```

ok sorry edit: check now

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but when I copy your code it gives me this error: TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'humour', 'physique', 'intelligence', and 'projet'        :/